# Textfield scroll to cursor

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm moving pages of my app to the jetpack compose. One of the simple pages in the old xml-based version has a simple EditText inside a LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView. Activity is using "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" in the manifest The text field usually contains enough text to cover the full screen, so when a user clicks to edit it, keyboard will cover big part of it. When you click on it, edittext will scroll content to the cursor location, moving content view up if needed.

In the compose version this doesn't happen however - I need to manually scroll to the cursor position. I tried using `bringIntoViewRequester` but it doesn't work for me. `imePadding` is added on the enclosing `Column` but it helps only when I scroll to the typing position.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're facing an issue with Jetpack Compose where the keyboard covers the text field when it's focused. To ensure that the cursor position is visible when the keyboard is open, you can use the `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned` in combination with `scrollState.animateScrollTo` to manually scroll the content.

This code calculates the offset of the text field from the top of the screen and scrolls to that position when the keyboard is opened. Make sure to adjust the code to fit your specific needs and layout.

```java
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Rect
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalView
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalViewConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                // Your Composable functions here
                MyScrollingContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScrollingContent() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val view = LocalView.current
    val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current
    var textFieldOffset by rememberUpdatedState(0)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = "Your long text here...",
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                    // Get the global position of the text field and calculate the offset
                    val rect: Rect = density.run { layoutCoordinates.boundsInParent().toRect() }
                    textFieldOffset = rect.top.toInt()
                }
                .keyboardOptions(KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done))
                .keyboardActions(onDone = {
                    // Handle keyboard 'Done' action
                })
        )
    }

    DisposableEffect(view) {
        val callback = ViewCompat.OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerCompat { _, event ->
            if (event.action == 1) {
                // Calculate the position to scroll to
                val insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
                val position = textFieldOffset - (insets?.systemGestureInsets?.top ?: 0) - viewConfiguration.touchSlop
                // Scroll to the calculated position
                scrollState.animateScrollTo(position)
            }
            false
        }
        ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(view, callback)
        onDispose {
            ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(view, callback)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried your code? it doesn't compile for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the `rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()` and `nestedScroll()` modifiers. These are part of the nested scrolling interop API that allows *Compose* to interact with *Traditional Android* views and vice versa.

First, you need to create a `NestedScrollConnection` using the `rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()` function. This connection will be used to handle nested scrolling interactions between *Compose* and *Traditional Android* views.

Then, you apply this connection to your top-level composable using the `nestedScroll()` modifier. This modifier is used to add the nested scroll connection to your top-level composable.

Example:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).apply {
       setContent {
           val nestedScrollInterop = rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()
           // Add the nested scroll connection to your top level @Composable element
           // using the nestedScroll modifier.
           LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollInterop)) {
               items(20) { item ->
                  Box(
                      modifier = Modifier
                          .padding(16.dp)
                          .height(56.dp)
                          .fillMaxWidth()
                          .background(Color.Gray),
                      contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                  ) {
                      Text(item.toString())
                  }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

In the sample above, a `LazyColumn` is used as the top-level composable. The `nestedScroll()` modifier is applied to this `LazyColumn`, and the `NestedScrollConnection` is passed to it. This setup will allow the `LazyColumn` to handle nested scrolling interactions with *Traditional Android* views.

However, it's important to note that Jetpack Compose's TextField doesn't have built-in support for automatically scrolling to the cursor position. You might need to manually implement this behavior by listening to the cursor position changes and programmatically scrolling to the new cursor position.

For example, you can use the `onTextLayout` parameter of the `TextField` composable to get the `TextLayoutResult` whenever the text layout changes. The `TextLayoutResult` contains information about the cursor position. You can then use this information to manually scroll to the cursor position.

Here is an example of how you can use the `onTextLayout` parameter:

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField() {
   var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

   TextField(
       value = text,
       onValueChange = { text = it },
       onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
           val cursorOffset = textLayoutResult.getCursorOffset()
           scrollState.value = cursorOffset
       },
       modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)
   )
}
```

the `onTextLayout` parameter is used to get the cursor offset whenever the text layout changes. This offset is then used to manually scroll to the cursor position using the `scrollState` of a `verticalScroll` modifier.

*"Please note that this is just a simplified example and might not cover all edge cases. You might need to adjust this code to fit your specific needs."*